# Regex for URI match (end of string)

Tags: regex

I have URIs like this:

```
/myurl/company/1234/add/task
/myurl/company/1234
/myurl/company/1234/remove/task
```

and a match like this:

```
"/myurl/company/(.)+/add/task"
"/myurl/company/(.)+/remove/task"
```

My question is this - what if I wanted to find the URI like this:

```
/myurl/company/1234
```

Because this will not work:

```
"/myurl/company/(.)+"
```

How do I anchor the regex to find anything that ends without another backlash (indicating more URI to come)?

Comment: `^` anchors to the beginning. `$` anchors to the end.  Use both to be thorough

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we wish to just capture those urls ending with digits, we can for instance use this expression:

```
^\/myurl\/company\/[0-9]+$
```

or:

```
\/myurl\/company\/[0-9]+$
```

#### [Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/cKHBlX/1/)

or, we can combine them with optional groups to capture all, if that'd be desired, such as with:

```
(\/myurl\/company\/[0-9]+)(\/add\/task)?(\/remove\/task)?
```

#### [Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/5GbT68/1/)

or, we would use logical ORs and capturing groups:

```
(\/myurl\/company\/[0-9]+)|(\/add\/task)|(\/remove\/task)
```

#### [Demo 3](https://regex101.com/r/2OGDv1/1/)

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

#### Advice

[Sunny](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1708751/sunny-patel) advises that:

> Instead of `[0-9]+`, you can use the Regular Expression for a UUID:
>   `[0-9a-f]{8}\b-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-\b[0-9a-f]{12}`

Comment: what would be the best approach if we use UUIDs instead of just ints (happens in a couple points)

Comment: @user10776719, instead of `[0-9]+`, you can use the Regular Expression for a UUID: `[0-9a-f]{8}\b-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-[0-9a-f]{4}-\b[0-9a-f]{12}`